# I do not want to skip a line after my input field

Tags: css

My front end look like this:

[image: password image]

I want to display this "Show" button inside my text field but I think due to **Form Control**, I am unable to do so.

Here is the code from Angular:
[image: angular code]

Comment: This is more a CSS than an angular question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to angular.
Just use `position: absolute` on your button.

```css
.form-group {
    width: 200px;
}

.form-control-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.show-password-button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <div class="form-control-wrapper"> 
      <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control">
      <button class="show-password-button">Show</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to align the button with the input, you can use `flexbox`:

Css:

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <div class="container">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" />
            <button>Show</button>
          </div>
   </div>
```